# my app have The local variable eror

Tags: java, android, variables, local

mytest say: The local variable mytest may not have been initialized

```
    final OnClickListener mytest = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Button mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mybtn.setOnClickListener(mytest);

}
```

Comment: Please show the part of the program where this error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain what your Code should do? Because this way of listener implementation can't be work. If you want to add an ClickListener to your button, than use this here:

```
Button mybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
            // Button clicked
     }
});
```